# What earth radius should I use to calculate distances near the Poles?

Tags: geolocation, haversine, cartography

I'm monitoring a GPS unit which is on it's way from Cape Discovery in Canada, to the North Pole. I need to keep track of the distance travelled and distance remaining each day, so I'm using the [Haversine Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), which I'm told is very accurate for smaller distances.

I'm really bad a Math, but I have a sneaking suspicion that the accuracy depends greatly on the radius of the Earth, and since the universe decided to make Earth out of an oblate spheroid, I have a [choice of approximations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius) for Earths radius to choose from.

Since I'm monitoring coordinates very close to the north pole, I'm wondering wether anyone knows which radius is going to provide the most accuracy.

- Mean Equatorial: 6,378.1370km
- Mean Polar:      6,356.7523
- Authalic/Volumetric: 6,371km
- Meridional: 6367km

Or any other kind of Radius that anyone knows about?

I'm hoping some maths or cartography whizz might know the answer to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could approximate the actual radius at the point(s) where you're measuring the distance (provided that you calculate a sequence of relative small distances).

Assuming the earth being an ellipsoid with the main axis *a* being the mean equatorial radius and the second axis *b* being the mean polar radius, you can calculate the point on the ellipse represented by these two axes by using the current latidude. The calculation is shown and explained [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180704211412/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54922.html).

(Note: This ellipse can be thought as a cross section of the earth through the poles and the point where you want to calculate the distance)

This gives you a point *q=(qx,qy)*, the radius at this point being *r=sqrt(qx^2+qy^2)*. That's what I'd use for calculating the Haversine formula.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter - they are all going to be wrong if you just treat the earth as a  sphere. I would probably use the polar since you are mostly going north.

Comment: is there a better way of doing it than using the Greater Circle Distance method?

Comment: I assume that you're calculating a series of smaller distances, so a spherical approximation should be ok. You can use different radii for each of these calculations as shown in my answer.